# best practice for models dependencies

Tags: node.js, git, web-deployment, package.json

I have serval custom packages in my project(its a my code, those packages are not in npm), each one in his own directory and has his own private repository.

**In dev:** I can use a package from a different packages using a relative path in package.json: (and npm link)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "customModule": "file:../other_module_relative_path"
  }
```

**In production:** I am just using the git repository:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "customModule": "git://github.com/.."
  }
```

So I have to maintain 2 different package.json
and to switch between them when deploying

Is there any better way do to it?

Comment: why you are doing this ?

Comment: Because on production I deploy the repositories to different servers so the dependency between them should be via the place they are hosted in (in this case Git). 
On dev I have all those packages under the same root folder so I use a relative path for fast development (if I change one package I don’t have to push it to Git in order to see the changes)

Comment: if you are using nodejs then no need to give library path manually. npm install packagename --save this command will save module in node_modules directory and also makes entry in package.json . So in your application you can use this package directly using var pkgname = require('packagename'); . Also when you install new package using --save. It will get added to package.json. So when you will commit package.json to server then on server just stop server fire npm install and after that start sever . all dependencies will get installed. no need to commit each dependency folder.

Comment: those packages are private, not in npm.
I Can't add them with 'npm add package-name --save' because there are not in npm, thats why I use relative path in packages.json

Comment: ok i got it . why you are using git path in production. you can do same as your doing in development

Comment: I upload each package to different server, there are not deploy to the same folder or even no in the same server.

Comment: why you are doing so ?

Comment: one is my api server , so I Deployed it to its own server.
the second is my client, so its also deployed separately (its a SPA)
other our utils packages that are use by both the client and the server.

each of them is develop separately.

Comment: For better performance  download packages to local machines and give paths.

Comment: It is on my local

Comment: then give path of local modules by var modulename= require('modulename')

Comment: you didn't understand my qh.

Comment: Hi @AJS, for developement - all the packages are local and you can add their path to the package json, but on production they might be deployed to different servers that's why the git path idea has came up. You're suggesting to download the packages to the computer and use local paths, but that doesn't solve the production case..